# Can final parameters be qualified in some way to resolve naming conflicts with anonymous class members?

Tags: java, scope, anonymous-class

"Why are you doing this what is wrong with you?" notwithstanding, is there any way to accomplish this without changing the final method parameter name?

```
private Foo createAnonymousFoo(final Bar bar) {
    return new Foo() {
        private Bar bar = SomeUnknownScopeQualifier.bar;

        public Bar getBar() {
            return bar;
        }

        public void doSomethingThatReassignsBar() {
            bar = bar.createSomeDerivedInstanceOfBar();
        }
    };
}
```

Obviously without the doSomethingThatReassignsBar call, you wouldn't need the member Bar and so on. In this case, the simple fix is to change `final Bar bar` to something like `final Bar startBar` and then the assignment is fine. But out of curiosity, is it possible to specifically refer to the `final Bar` (Similar to the way you would say `Super.this`)?

Comment: "Why are you doing this what is wrong with you?" :)

Comment: It's actually not as reprehensible as you might imagine. I'd created a document builder and was using the visitor pattern to write items, and in the case of a spreadsheet I was simply iterating over cells starting at a "startCell" (the final method param) and moving through them with `cell = cell.nextCell()`, where cell was the ItemVisitor's current cell to write to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is "no". From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4):

> A local variable (§14.4), formal parameter (§8.4.1), exception parameter (§14.20), and local class (§14.3) can only be referred to using a simple name (§6.2), not a qualified name (§6.6).

In other words, there's nothing you can replace `SomeUnknownScopeQualifier` with in your example code to make the assignment statement in the inner class refer to the formal parameter name.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not possible to do that. Rename the involved variables or create an alias:

```
private Foo createAnonymousFoo(final Bar bar) {
  final Bar alias = bar; 
  return new Foo() {
    private Bar bar = alias;

    // ...
  };
}
```

Comment: This seems no different than just naming the method parameter `alias`?

Comment: The method parameter name might be available to code completion tools or the like. Thus, it's better to have the self-documenting name in the public API and use a distinct (though possibly cryptic) name internally.

Comment: That's a great point. I've upvoted this as it is a useful and insightful answer. The answer from Alex, however, cites the JLS and I feel I should accept that one.