# Access parameter from anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have a (pedantic) Java question: I want to create an anonymous class in a method and assign a method parameter to a member with the same name. The code below does not work as it assigns the member to itself.

```java
class TestClass {
    String id;
}

TestClass createTestClass(final String id) {
    return new TestClass() {{
        this.id = id; // self assignment of member
    }};
}
```

Beside the obvious method to rename the id parameter, is there any other way to access it? Thx

Comment: do you want an anonymous class just for the assignment of the `id` field?

Comment: @wero I think this is just a simplified example of the general concept :D

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need an anonymous class here?

Comment: It's an simplified example. id is protected in a different package and not accessible from the outside.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155269/access-shadowed-variable-from-anonymous-class)?

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144789/can-final-parameters-be-qualified-in-some-way-to-resolve-naming-conflicts-with-a/10145300#10145300)

Comment: yes. so it's not possible. thx anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the anonymous class

```
TestClass createTestClass(final String id) {
     TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
     testClass.id = id;
     return testClass;
}
```

or rename the parameter

```
TestClass createTestClass(final String theId) {
    return new TestClass() {{
        this.id = theId; 
    }};
}
```

or drop the factory method all together by introducing a constructor parameter:

```
class TestClass {
    public TestClass(String id) { this.id = id; }
    String id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic, `Java 8` Snippet to achieve the same:

```
Function<String, TestClass> createTestClass = TestClass::new;
```

Usage:

```
final class TestClass {
    private final String id;

    public TestClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
};

public class AnyClass {
    static Function<String, TestClass> createTestClass = TestClass::new;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass testclass = createTestClass.apply("hello");
        System.out.println(testclass.getId());
    }
}
```